# Mixed Effects Model: Writing Out Level 1/Level 2 Models

Tags: mixed-model

Suppose I have an LMER output (using Grunfeld data from plm package) as:

```
summary(lmer(inv ~ value + capital + (1|firm), data = Grunfeld))

> Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 firm     (Intercept) 7367     85.83    
 Residual             2781     52.74    0.831
Number of obs: 200, groups:  firm, 10

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) -57.86442   29.37776   -1.97
value         0.10979    0.01053   10.43
capital       0.30819    0.01717   17.95

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr) value 
value   -0.328       
capital -0.019 -0.368
```

I know we can write a Level 1/Level 2 model based on this as:

```
Level 1:
y = alpha_0 + alpha_1 * value + alpha_2 * capital + eps
Level 2:
alpha_0 = gamma_00 + u_0
alpha_1 = gamma_01 + u_1
alpha_2 = gamma_02 + u_2
```

The level 1 model should have alpha_0=-57.864, alpha_1=0.109, alpha_2=0.308.

Now, I'm actually not sure if this is the correct form of the level 2 model. Im wondering what exactly the level 1/2 models would be here (for example, are the gammas in the level 2 model concrete values, or are they RV's. For example, [here](https://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer), it is not clear what those values are supposed to be). And also what the correlation of the fixed effects means versus the correlation of random effects. I can't seem to find definitive answers online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you have only included a random intercept for the `firm` grouping variable. I.e., the model you are fitting is the following:

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\texttt{Inv}_{ij} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \texttt{Value}_{ij} + \beta_2 \texttt{Capital}_{ij} + b_i + \varepsilon_{ij},\\\\
b_i \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma_b^2), \quad \varepsilon_{ij} \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2),
\end{array}
\right.$$

where $\texttt{Inv}_{ij}$ denotes the $j$-th measurement within the $i$-th firm for you outcome variable, and likewise $\texttt{Value}_{ij}$ and $\texttt{Capital}_{ij}$ denote the $j$-th measurement within the $i$-th firm for the two predictors.

The estimated parameters according to the output are:

- $\hat\beta_0 = -57.86442$
- $\hat\beta_1 = 0.10979$
- $\hat\beta_2 = 0.30819$
- $\hat\sigma_b = 85.83$
- $\hat\sigma = 52.74$

You could also rewrite the same model as:

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\texttt{Inv}_{ij} = \alpha_{0i} + \beta_1 \texttt{Value}_{ij} + \beta_2 \texttt{Capital}_{ij} + \varepsilon_{ij},\\\\
\alpha_{0i} = \beta_0 + b_i,\\\\
b_i \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma_b^2), \quad \varepsilon_{ij} \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2).
\end{array}
\right.$$

Comment: Thank you! This is great. I have also been trying to understand what the correlation of random effects exactly represents. For example, I understand the correlation of fixed effects measures the correlation between coefficients for each of the individual fits. But what does the correlation of random effects show?

Comment: It is not clear which correlation you exactly mean. You only have a single random intercept per firm. BTW, when I run the same example in my laptop, I don't get the `Corr` column in the Random Effects output.

Comment: My apologies, you are correct. Suppose I run this code: summary(lmer(inv ~ value + capital + (1+value|firm), data = Grunfeld)). We see the correlation of random effects is -0.40. What does this term represent, exactly? The correlation of fixed effects measures the correlation between the coefficients for individual fits (which can be confirmed with, say, looking at LmList) but I cannot see what the -0.40 correlation for random effects corresponds to.

Comment: This is the (prior) correlation between the random intercepts and random slopes for `value`. Because it is negative it indicates that a-priori firms which have a positive intercept will tend to have a negative slope, and the otherway around.

Comment: Thats what I thought, but if I do the following: x=lmer(inv ~ value + capital + (1+value|firm), data = Grunfeld), then: cor(ranef(x)\$firm[,1], ranef(x)\$firm[,2]), I get a value of -0.3, not -0.4, which does not make sense to me... where exactly would we see what the -0.4 is measuring?

Comment: Indeed, this why I mentioned in my comment above that this is the prior correlation between the random intercepts and random slopes. The `ranef()` function gives you the means/modes of the *posterior* distribution of these random effects given the observed data. Hence, the correlation you calculate is the *a-posteriori* correlation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are 10 firms in the dataset.

Level 1 model:

$$Y_{ki}=\alpha_{0k} + \alpha_1X_{1ki} + \alpha_2X_{2ki} + \epsilon_{ki}$$

So the level 2 model can be written as:

$$\alpha_{0k} = \alpha_0 + u_k$$

where $k=,...,10$ is index for firm. $i$ is the i-th measurement. $X_{1ki}$ is value and $X_{2ki}$ capital.

$u_k\sim N(0,\sigma_u^2)$ and $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.